# Convert Row To Column displaying percentage totals

Tags: sql-server-2008

I know pretty much how to do a pivot, but i ran into an issue that I cannot figure out.  I have this data set that contains "Site" as text (row-vertical), Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q7 as Percentage (%) total (column-horizontal), and my issue is that I want to display the Site as a column and Q1 to Q7 as a row, and i just cannot figure out how to do it.  Can someone assist me?

Thanks.

Comment: Some sample data, desired output and your attempt so far would be nice!!

Comment: Please provide code for what you've attempted so far to solve the solution. Right now it comes off as you're simply wanting someone to write the code for you without actually attempting to do so yourself.

Comment: select * into #a from ( select s.Site, s.Q1, s.Q2, s.Q3, s.Q4 s.Q5, s.Q6, s.Q7 from tbl s ) as x PIVOT ( count(surveyid) for [monthday] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31]) ) as results -- i want to replace the days with site.

Comment: But my issue is how can i use pivot replacing the columns with Q1 to Q7. Meaning use site as columns and q1 to q7 as row..that was my template that i used for my other project.. but this one is a bit challenging for me since m not a hardcore sql expert

Answer (score 1):

Its not pretty much clear the expected output from your question. But since you asked

> I want to display the Site as a column and Q1 to Q7 as a row

you need to bring columns as row and convert row to columns. For this you need to `unpivot` first and then pivot next.

**Note : The column name of your table and the sample table may be different. But follow the approach I have used.**

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP([SITE] VARCHAR(10),Q1 INT,Q2 INT,Q3 INT,Q4 INT,Q5 INT,Q6 INT,Q7 INT)

 INSERT INTO #TEMP
 SELECT 'A',1,3 ,4,2,7,8,9
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'B',2,6 ,9,4,8,11,12
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'C',10,3 ,2,5,6,4,9
```

**QUERY**

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to `unpivot` the columns to rows.

**(a) When the values in rows are known in advance, you can use static pivot.**

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (
     SELECT [SITE],VAL,COLNAME
     FROM #TEMP
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES (Q1,'Q1'),(Q2,'Q2'),(Q3,'Q3'),(Q4,'Q4'),(Q5,'Q5'),(Q6,'Q6'),(Q7,'Q7'))
     COLUMNNAMES(VAL,COLNAME)
 )R
 PIVOT 
 ( 
     MIN(VAL)
     for [SITE] in ([A],[B],[C])
 )AS P
```

**- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c5df/1) to view result**

**(b) When the values in the row in unknown in advance, you can use dynamic pivot.**

```
-- Get the values in the row and store in a variable
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + [SITE] + ']', '[' + [SITE] + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [SITE] FROM #TEMP) PV 
               ORDER BY [SITE]

-- Convert the values to dynamic number of columns       
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT [SITE],VAL,COLNAME
                 FROM #TEMP
                 CROSS APPLY(VALUES (Q1,''Q1''),(Q2,''Q2''),(Q3,''Q3''),
                                    (Q4,''Q4''),(Q5,''Q5''),(Q6,''Q6''),(Q7,''Q7''))
                 COLUMNNAMES(VAL,COLNAME)
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(VAL)
                 FOR [SITE] in  (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY COLNAME;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9b6f/1) to view result**